# Laravel eloquent one to many relation where statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following models in laravel eloquent

```
class InterviewList extends Eloquent{

protected  $table = 'interviewlists';

public function subject(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Subject','id_subject','id');
}}

class Subject extends Eloquent{

public  function interviewList(){

    return $this->hasMany('InterviewList');
}}
```

I need to get Ids of interviewList table that subjects name is "java", 
in subject table i have (id,name) columns, and in interviewList table (id,name,id_subject).
I'va tried the following code

```
 $interviewListId = InterviewList::with('Subject')->whereName('java')->get(array('id'));
```

but it just gives no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get ids of Interview list that has subjects with name `java` you should use:

```
$ids = InterviewList::whereHas('subject',  function($q)
{
    $q->where('name', 'java');

})->lists('id');
```

Comment: That worked fine, but just one question will this functions get all columns from DB that show 'id', or get jus id column which is faster ?

Comment: @Redadublex It will get just `id` in DB query from  table assigned to `InterView List` model

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

```
Subject::where('name', 'like', '%java%')-> interviewList()->get(array('id'));
```